# Jfrog container registry (JFrog cloud) configuration on openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-enterprise, jfrog-cli

I am unable to configure my `openshift` to connect with the `docker registry` hosted on `Jfrog docker registry`.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this command?

```
$ docker login <SERVER_NAME>-docker.jfrog.io
```

If yes, please share the error you received